# Is Lookup Auto-Completion really restricted to recent items?

Tags: custom-object, lookup, filters, search

We are using the Salesforce search setting "Lookup Auto-Completion" which provides auto-completed options as-you-type in lookup filters on your visual force pages.

The suggested results that pop-up beneath the lookup as you type are headed with "My Recent Items" - and the Salesforce documentation insists that the results shown will be filtered through the users recent items in that object... however, I do not believe this is the behaviour we are experiencing. For example, this is a brand new user on my application, using a "Country__c" lookup, and as soon as you enter 'F' the suggestions are for all three F countries we have, despite the fact this user has definitely never opened, modified or encountered these records..

[image: Country lookup]

Has anyone else experienced this unusual behaviour and/or is there a setting/configuration I can adjust to change it?

Edit to say: This setting does not appear to affect this:
[image]

Comment: It should be limited to just recently viewed/created items for the user. Were you using Login Access or directly logged in as the new user? I suppose there might be a session-based glitch, but the user definitely shouldn't see recent items if they've never used the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to test this, if you find the Lookup is strange, use current user to click the "Country__c" Object Tab, by default you will see the Recent list for this user.
It should be the same with what you can see in the "Lookup Auto-Completion" field.

Check the link below,
[How many and how long does enhanced lookup store my Most Recently Used items?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005596&language=en_US)

The Summer 08 feature Enhanced Lookups / Auto-completion stores your Most Recently Used (MRU) items so that you can access them quickly. It will store 100 used items and will only replace when a new item is used. The items are stored server side, so they are available from any computer.